# @viewChild return undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have checked other answer for this problems but nothing seems helpful so far. I'm trying to display map in ionic 2 app. But When I try to select `#map` div it returns undefined. Here is the code

page1.html
`<div id="map" #mapDiv style="height:380px;"></div>`

page1.ts

```ts
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html',
})
export class Page1 implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('mapDiv') mapDiv:ElementRef;
    map;
    t;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.initMap();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log('My element: ' + this.mapDiv);
  }

  initMap()
  {
     this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapDiv.nativeElement,  {  
                  center:  new  google.maps.LatLng(51.505,  -0.09),  
                  mapTypeId:  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,  
                  zoom:  11  
              });  

    this.t = new Date().getTime();  
      var  waqiMapOverlay  =  new  google.maps.ImageMapType({  
                  getTileUrl:  function(coord,  zoom)  {  
                            return  'http://tiles.aqicn.org/tiles/usepa-aqi/'  +  zoom  +  "/"  +  coord.x  +  "/"  +  coord.y  +  ".png?token=_TOKEN_ID_";  
                  },  
                  name:  "Air  Quality",  
        });  

      this.map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0,waqiMapOverlay);  
  }

}
```

console errors

```ts
`Error in ./Page1 class Page1_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`
```

Please tell me where I'm mistaking. I want to select the div so that the map can be shown inside of `#map` div.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 @ViewChild annotation returns undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call `initMap()` in the constructor.

`@ViewChild('mapDiv') mapDiv:ElementRef;`  is not initialized before `ngAfterViewInit()` is called.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm still learning. That solved my problem. Amazing. Thanks again.