# @ViewChild always returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I know this has been asked before, but none of the selected answers are working for me.

I am trying to use `@ViewChild` to get my `ng-select` from the dom. And it always returns undefined.

here is the select inside the `main.html`:

```
<ng-select id = "user-select" 
     #userSelect 
     [allowClear]="true"
     [items]="singleSignOnUsers"
     [disabled]="disabled"
     placeholder="No user selected">
</ng-select>
```

here is my component

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-main',
    templateUrl: '../app/main.html',
    providers: [ApiHttpService, UserAdministrationService]
})

export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('userSelect') userSelect;


    ngAfterViewInit() {
        alert(this.userSelect);
    }
}
```

what am i missing here?

Update: Oh My Soul!
I figured out why this wasn't working when it should.

I have the whole view wrapped in a `div` with an `ngSwitch`. If I move it out I can access them.

Now I don't know how to access them while in the `ngSwitch` however. But I don't have to use the `ngSwitch`.

```
<div [ngSwitch]='loading'>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="false">
            ...
            <ng-select id="user-select"
                       #userSelect
                       [allowClear]="true"
                       [items]="singleSignOnUsers"
                       [disabled]="disabled"
                       placeholder="No city selected">
            </ng-select>
            ...
        </div>
    <div
```

Comment: This should work. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: I have never used plunker. I will see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Plunker provides a ready to use Angular2 TS template under the `[ New | v ]` button.

Comment: Does the ng-select actually show up? Are the components registered in the module?

Comment: yes the ng-select does show up. I also get the same issue when just using a div or regular select and not an ng-select

Comment: Does it make any difference to implement `AfterViewInit` with your `AppComponent`?

Comment: see update. It is the ngSwitch that was causing the weirdness.

Comment: When i test ng2-select  dom object return and all work.Could you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 @ViewChild annotation returns undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

@twaldron Are you using some delayed data loading in ngOnInit?

Because in that case, in my experience, reading a @ViewChild as a ElementRef produces no results

If your component has the data already resolved (like the case when a parent passes a child data object to a sub component) it should work (at least for me it did).

In the case of asynchronous data loading, the way I was able to make it work is using a change notification

```
 @ViewChildren('userSelect') userSelect: QueryList<ElementRef>;

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.userSelect.changes.subscribe(item => {
        if (this.userSelect.length) {
            alert(this.userSelect.first.nativeElment.outerHTML)
        }
    })
 }
```

Comment: Thant makes sense I believe. I have it wrapped in the ngSwitch which shows a loading gif while the data is aquired async. When the data is done loading it is then switched and the element is shown. Ultimately I will be setting the items property of the select to the loaded data which is why i am trying to access it in the first place.

Comment: This worked for me `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngOnInit` too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced all occurrences of

```
*ngIf="flag"
```

with

```
[style.display]="flag ? 'block' : 'none'"
```

to get this to work consistently in my case. Otherwise the `ViewChild` components that didn't exist when my view first loaded would potentially remain undefined for ever.

Comment: This doesn't work with model bindings unfortunately and i think your solution would improve with `[hidden]="!flag"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I encountered the same problem. I `console.log()`-ed the content that is retrieved from the child component and it gives me 'undefined'.

And I solved it by merely refreshing the page. `ctrl`+`shift`+`R` may help. I guess it's because the cache of the browser that leads to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

ngSwitch was exactly the reason. (and for that case ngIf doesn't work either)

Fixed it using classes so that it still renders everything and just hides it.

CSS

```
.show{
  display: block !important;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div [ngClass]="{'show': someVariable === 'someVariable'}" class="hide">
   <input type="text" #search />
 </div>
```

Edit: the answer of @Sreeram Nair also works, even a bit more elegant.