# ViewChild does undefined during resize event

Tags: angular, events, viewchild

Let's see:

```
import {
  Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  template: `
  <aside #sidebar>
  Sidebar
  </aside>`,
})
export class AppSidebar implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('sidebar')
  private sidebar: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('OnInit has:', this.sidebar)
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resetSidebar);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('AfterViewInit has:', this.sidebar);
  }

  resetSidebar() {
    console.log(this.sidebar);
  }
}
```

`this.sidebar` is volatile here. It logs out correctly during the lifecycle hooks, but when you resize the window it becomes null. No [camelCase problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256703/angular-2-viewchild-returns-undefined), no [conditional dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427748/viewchild-always-returns-undefined), so what's wrong with the code?

Comment: I guess `resize` is fired already before `sidebar` is set. You subscribe in `ngOnInit()` but `sidebar` will only be available in the later `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter. When I subscribe in `ngAfterViewInit` or even in `ngAfterContentInit` - the result is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by how you register the event handlers.

With

```
 window.addEventListener('resize', this.resetSidebar);
```

`this` inside `resetSidebar` doesn't point to the `AppSidebar` class anymore.

Use `.bind(this)` to ensure `this` keeps working

```
 window.addEventListener('resize', this.resetSidebar.bind(this);
```

You can also use arrow functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
 window.addEventListener('resize', (event) => this.resetSidebar(event);
```

Comment: Yup, good catch. The freedom of `this` in TS does not go that far ;-)