# this.nav is undefined - Ionic2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having a problem with this piece of code here:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Page1 } from '../page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../page2/page2';
import { Login } from '../auth/login/login';
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class Home {
    @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
    rootHomePage: any = Page1;
    pages: Array<{title: string, action: any}>;
    user = this.navPrm.get('auth').current_user();
    constructor(public navPrm: NavParams) {
        console.log("TesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTeste");
        console.log(this.nav);
        // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
        this.pages = [
            { title: 'Page One', action: this.openPage(Page1) },
            { title: 'Page Two', action: this.openPage(Page2) },
            { title: 'Logout', action: this.user.logout() }
        ];
    }
    openPage(page) {
        // Reset the content nav to have just this page
        // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
        this.nav.setRoot(page);
    }
}
```

So, on the openPage() method, the this.nav (the nav is declared above) is returning an error: this.nav is undefined. Someone has any idea why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined perhaps this link helps to figure out the nullpointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `this.nav.rootNav.setRoot(page)`. This should work. It works for me.

One more thing, isn't `user = this.navPrm.get('auth').current_user();` is supposed to be inside the constructor when you are retrieving the value from `navParam`.
(Since, I am not familiar with your code, not sure about this part though. Just seemed wrong.)

Comment: The problem resides on the this.nav... since it is undefined, I just can't access any methods of the Nav prototype...

Comment: I have also tough this a bit weird  the user statement, but it's currently working, so... kkk

Comment: Just try to get that inside and see. I know it's a long shot, but, that could be a problem. Also, if not, you need to show the entire code. As in where are you setting this page from? Is this the start of the app? Also, show the home.html code as well.

Comment: Also, if it is not start of the app, then try having `constructor(private navCtrl: NavController)` and then try `this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page)` and if it works. Also, try removing the @ViewChild and see what happens. Let me know what is the output of all these trials.

Comment: By trying, I ended up figuring this out... But Thanks... rs

Comment: What did you figure out?

Comment: I have added `navCtrl: NavController` to the constructor and replaced from `Nav` dependencie to `NavController`, and then `this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page)`