# Can't able to access child component function from parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

I have a separate assetAnnotationComponent(child) which manages the annotating functionality.This component is called from my main component to perform annotation on images by mouse events.Iam getting the following error when accessing the **assetAnnotationComponent** object

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'mychildFunction' of undefined
```

I tried like  following in my parent component
`@ViewChild(AssetAnnotationComponent) assetAnnotationComponent`

Here is parent component HTML

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <app-asset-annotation></app-asset-annotation>
  </div>
```

Here is parent component typescript

```
import { AssetAnnotationComponent } from './asset-annotation.component';

export class ParentComponent{
@ViewChild(AssetAnnotationComponent) assetAnnotationComponent;

ngAfterViewInit(){
this.assetAnnotationComponent.mychildFunction();
}
}
```

my child component

```
export class AssetAnnotationComponent{

mychildFunction()
{
console.log("success");
}

}
```

I am expecting "success" to printed in console so that i can be accessing the child component's function.Thanks in advance

Edit:
As suggested in comments and from the question that is suggested as duplicate, i have already tried that. I am using ngViewAfterInit for calling my function so view is loaded completely.
Edit 2: My child component is from different module

**Edit 2: My child component is from different module**

[here is my sample working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srdeba?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**In my code if the selector of the child component is added in parent component html then i get desired output but i need to access the child component function without adding selector of child component in parent component**

Comment: Is that **all** of the `ParentComponent` HTML? Or does the parent HTML have any `*ngIf` or similar conditional rendering logic?

Comment: You seem to have the `AssetAnnotationComponent` in a Modal that you probably are showing in your `ParentComponent` conditionally. Hence you're not getting the reference to it in your ParentComponent via ViewChild. And hence the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 @ViewChild annotation returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined)

Comment: You will find two possible solutions in [the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34947154/1009922): (1) using `ViewChildren` with `QueryList.changes`, (2) using a setter for `ViewChild`.

Comment: There is no conditional structure around this div. I have one button, on which i need to call the function of child element, which is not being called and i am getting undefined.

Comment: @ConnorsFan i have checked that question and as you can see in my question i am calling my function in ngAfterViewInit only.

Comment: @shyamsundar - Yes but you should check the other answers to the duplicate question, not the accepted answer. You will find two solutions (mentioned in my previous comment) that should work for you.

Comment: @SiddAjmera this looks like the case, i dont have any conditional structure but entire code is loaded on button click, so there might be no reference when button is clicked. In that case how do i solve this?

Comment: @ConnorsFan i tried with viewchildren it was also not happening.My problem is similar to siddAjmera comment

Comment: Is that the only ancestor in the template of your component? or does the template has more hierarchy levels for that element?

Comment: It's the only one @jota.toledo

Comment: @shyamsundar https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oefm77?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts no issues there. Can you reproduce your issue in stackblitz or similar?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo i have added my sample code in stackblitz

Comment: _i need to access the child component function without adding selector of child component_ then its not a child component

Comment: i need to access the child component function without adding selector of child component in parent component HTML @Jota.Toledo

Comment: Again, if its not present in the template of the component, then it is **not** a child component. Ergo, you cant use `ViewChild`.

Answer (score 2):

in your parent component do this:

```
@ViewChildren('myChild') assetAnnotationComponent: QueryList<AssetAnnotationComponent>; 
public currentChildComponent: AssetAnnotationComponent;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
          this.assetAnnotationComponent.changes.subscribe(data => {
              this.currentChildComponent= data._results[0];
              this.currentChildComponent.mychildFunction();
          });
    }
```

Parent HTML do this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <app-asset-annotation #myChild></app-asset-annotation>  //notice the template variable
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a reference to the child:

```
<app-asset-annotation #child></app-asset-annotation>
```

and then in the .ts:

```
@ViewChild('child') child;
```

then you could call it as:

```
this.child.mychildFunction();
```

Comment: I exactly tried this already but it was not working.Thanks for your reply@fisnik

Comment: I realize you need it for dynamically created children.. Seems that @Nadhir's answer takes care of it!

Comment: I tested the ViewChildren approach and added childrenComponents dynamically on button click, and it works!

Comment: i have edited my question i forgot to mention that my child component is from different module @Fisnik

Comment: As I stated in the comments above, the code I used to test is from @Nadhir Falta's answer, you can give it a shot!