# Set ViewChild after ajax call

Tags: angular, typescript

I set element reference to my input,

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{

    @ViewChild("mySearchElement") // <input #mySearchElement 
    public searchElementRef: ElementRef;
```

...and bind it with google maps autosearch, which **works fine**.

```
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, ...
```

What I try to do is, I want to render whole template after ajax call is completed. So I added a property to my component,

```
public isDataLoaded = false
```

and I set this true only after ajax work is completed.

```
<div *ngIf="isDataLoaded">
    ....my search element is within this wrapper.
```

...but when I do this, autocomplete cannot find searchElementRef, which is **understandable**.

How can I set viewchild after my ajax call is completed? This doesn't work:

```
function ajaxCallCompleted() { // Callback once ajax is completed.
    this.isDataLoaded = true
    @ViewChild("mySearchElement") this.searchElementRef: ElementRef;
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement ....
}
```

Comment: Use `[style.display]="isDataLoaded ? 'block' : 'none'"` instead of `*ngIf`

Comment: I need to use *ngIf, style doesn't work in my flow for different reasons.

Comment: well you can't, so you'll have to find another way. it's either the style or `document.querySelector`, and I don't advise the latter one.

Comment: Try initializing the element with `@ViewChildren()`. Similar question to [Angular 2 @ViewChild annotation returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I carried search input to a different component and now all works fine.

```
<div *ngIf="isDataLoaded">
   <app-location-search location="data.location">...
```

Now on my sub component I can bind with google maps autocomplete like this:

```
export class LocationSearchComponent{

    @Input() location: any;

    @ViewChild("mySearchElement") public searchElementRef: ElementRef;

    constructor(public mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {

    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because it cannot find the element reference. Use the hidden property instead:

```
<div [hidden]="!isDataLoaded">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I said it worked...but caused other problems about my flow. I need to find a way with *ngIf.