# How to wait in Angular 7 until DOM changed ready?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a list of entries. When I click on such an entry a HTTP request is done, data will be loaded and presented in a table. So far so good.

Now I try to create an export function to output all tables at once. The abstracted code looks like this:

```
this.objectlist.forEach(entry => {

    this.getDataFromHTTP(entry).subscribe(response => {
        tabledata.push(this.getTableDOM());
    })

})
```

In the function `getTableDOM()` I do something like `let table = document.getElementsByClassName(data.classname);`. The code itself runs when I click every entry. But it doesn't work within the `forEach()`.

The real problem is that the `getTableDOM()` returns an empty result, because the DOM isn't ready when it is called.

So my question is: how can I wait until DOM changes are done before I call `getTableDOM()`. Or maybe my approach to achieve my goal is completely wrong. But if so: how can I do it otherwise?

Thx for your help!
Lars

Comment: have you try ` ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit()` is called just once after the initial view is ready. In my case the view is rendered and `ngAfterViewInit()` has already been called whenI click the export button.

Comment: Would you mind creating a demo example on stackblitz.com ? That could give us more insight

Comment: @ShashankVivek, I thought about, but the code is a bit too complex for a demo and a simplification is not that easy. Unfortunately!

Comment: @LarsHagen why don't you use a promise to hold loading the DOM until data is received.

Comment: @AzkarMoulana please can you give an (abstract) code example?

Comment: Your questions isn't clear. After http request data is presented in table. Fine. My question is when do you call, say, export() function. In the code snippet you have provided for export function, why is there a `getDataFromHTTP` what is the role of http call in exporting? What is `objectlist`? Sorry but I cant make sense of the snippet you have provided.

Comment: @dasfdsa, well 'ok' my code snippet is really just a small "abstract" piece of code. Let me try to explain: `objectlist` contains a list of `ID`s which are used as parameters for the HTTP calls. E.g. `http://www.example.com/rest/get/1` where `1` is an `ID`. Now I have a button that calls an `export()` function. My goal is - when pressing the button - the all `ID`s from `objectlist` are loaded - one after each other. But finally, I need the DOM of the tables for further processing. I'm using a JS library that expects to get a DOM to export it to Excel.

Comment: Seems like a good use case for something like [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [DEMO](https://angular-jgrtwz.stackblitz.io) I've created, hopefully, it'll get you going in the right direction. Like others have mentioned from what you've provided it's difficult to get the full picture. I think what you're looking for is something like [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges), I've included relevant example code below. I've also included in the demo a [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) example.

```js
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  SimpleChanges
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'on-change',
  template: `
        <pre>
            {{changes | json}}
        </pre>
    `
})
export class OnChangeComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() data: any;
  changes;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.changes = changes;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach I never thought about. I will give it a try. Please can you provide the full source code of the Demo. I'd like to see how you use the forkjoin. I can "only" see the working example.

Comment: @LarsHagen just click on the word demo, should take you to the full demo. Where you can fully interact with

Comment: I did. What happens is that a white screen with the running demo opens - and only the demo. But there is no source code visible.

Comment: @LarsHagen https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgrtwz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fonchanges.component.ts

Comment: I will test your approach within the next days (before I have to go on a business trip). If it works I will do it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use DOM as a source of data like you are doing. Anyways, you can detect the changes manually to render the DOM and in next tick export the content.

```
constructor(private changeDetector : ChangeDetectorRef) {}

this.objectlist.forEach(entry => {
    this.getDataFromHTTP(entry).subscribe(response => {
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();//if using push stratagy
        setTimeout(_=>tabledata.push(this.getTableDOM()));
    })
})
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined) question

You can mark your tables and access them using `viewChildren`

```
@ViewChildren("mytable") mytable;

this.mytable.changes.subscribe((el)=>{
    /*check if desired table node exists on el*/
});
```

Answer (score -3):

This will check every 2 secs ...

```
public static void AngWait(){
    WebDriverWait jsWait jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String angular5Check = (String) jsExec.executeScript("return getAllAngularRootElements()[0].attributes['ng-version'].value");
    System.out.println(angular5Check);
    if (angular5Check != null) {
        do {
            angularPageLoaded = (Boolean) jsExec.executeScript("return window.getAllAngularTestabilities().findIndex(x=>!x.isStable()) === -1");
            System.out.println("in loop => "+angularPageLoaded);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

        } while (!angularPageLoaded);

        System.out.println("outside loop => "+angularPageLoaded);
    }

}
```

Comment: What does it have to do with WebDriver? oO

Comment: while the webpage is loading, the angular wait will keep on checking in every 2 secs whether the loader is rolling or not.. Once the loader is gone, then it will assume that the next page/ event is ready.