# Angular Router: Cannot read property ' ' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, typeerror

im trying to implement Routing in my programm. The basic routing works if i type in the URL in the browser. However if i want to use my button from the MainComponent Im getting an error:**Cannot read property 'loadFromJson' of undefined.**

Before I implemented the Router it just worked fine like it is now.

My app-routing.module:

```
...
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'start',        component: FrontPageComponent },
{ path: 'action',        component: MainComponent },
{ path: '',   redirectTo: '/start', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
  ];
...
```

My Main component calls a function with a button. Part of the function however calls another function which is in the child component.

MainComponent.html:

```
  <button routerLink="/action" type="submit" (click)="function()" >Load</button>
   ..
   ..
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

MainComponent.ts

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent; <--imported ChildComponent with @ViewChild
      ...
      function(): void { 
        this.DownloadService.downloadResource(this.url).subscribe(
          json => this.childComponent.loadFromJson(json, this.url),   <--function from childComponent
          err => this.setError(err),
        );
      }
```

Function in the child Component:

childComponent.ts:

```
 private loadFromJson(json: any, id: string): void {
   this.initEmptyContainer();
   this.addFromJson(json, id);
}
 ...
```

Why cant it read the property and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? Note that all latest versions of angular uses a second parameter for the ViewChild.

Comment: @AngelaAmarapala as he don't get an error about viewchild static parameter her use less than version 8

Comment: @AngelaAmarapala im using 7.3.8

Answer (score 0):

To refer a class variable inside your method use `this.childComponent`

Try this

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent;

...

function(): void { 
    this.DownloadService.downloadResource(this.url).subscribe(
      json => this.childComponent.loadFromJson(json, this.url),   // <-- Refer your childComponent using this
      err => this.setError(err),
    );
}
```

Comment: In that case check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34947154/3094731) answer

Comment: When im usinf ViewCildren it says this: .loadFromJson is not a function

Answer (score 0):

the view queries are set before the ngAfterViewInit callback is called.

```js
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent;

 downloadResource (): void { 
  this.DownloadService.downloadResource(this.url).subscribe(
     json => this.childComponent.loadFromJson(json, this.url),
          err => this.setError(err),
        );
      }

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.downloadResource();
  }
```

check [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) for more details

Comment: @pattplatt I have update the like , dis the answer solve your problem ?

Comment: unfortunately not, I tried it with
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.resourceDownloadService.downloadResource()
  }
still the same error

Comment: However if I use @ViewChildren i get the Error:
.loadFromJson is not a function