# Managing the ngx-owl-carousel-o from outside its markup, undefined template reference Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, owl-carousel

I am trying to go to a specific position of ngx-owl-carousel-o, after following the below tutorial from the tips section.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o#tips

**Please note this is**: owl-carousel-o not owl-carousel library

However, the the error I am getting is that the template reference on the owl-carousel-o tag is undefined when trying to call owlCar.to():
[image]

Tutorial from docs:

[image]

I have also tried printing the view child of the reference in the Typescript file but this is also returning undefined!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my question for anyone else who comes across this issue!
Adding to the answer from Vitali, the CarouselModule had already been imported, which was not the issue.

So the solution I found relates to the below issue of template references being killed if they are within a ngIf* directive.

[Angular 2 @ViewChild annotation returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined?rq=1)

Template references also become undefined within other Angular directives such as ng-template! So please keep note of this.

I hope this helped and Thank you Vitali for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't imported `CarouselModule` into module that declares component using `<owl-carousel-o... >`

```js
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CarouselModule ],
  declarations: [ CarouselHolderComponent ]
})
export class SomeModule { }
```