# Ngafterviewinit, @viewchild element is undefined

Tags: angular

@ViewChild('videoPlayer') myVidElement: ElementRef;

I have html5 video elemnt in markup with view child as above

that element is not becoming accessible, it is logged undefined both in ngOnInit & ngAfterViewInit method

My goal is to extract video duration , code is as follows

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void { 
   console.log("after view init -- " + this.myVidElement); 
   this.eventsService.videoLengthInSeconds = this.myVidElement.nativeElement.duration; 
 }
```

html as follows

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between start" 
    class="ats-analyzer ats-p-t-10" *ngIf=" currentParticipant">    
  
  <div fxFlex="45%" class="ats-analyzer--video ats-p-r-10">         
    <video controls #videoPlayer>
      <source [src]="atsAnalyzerVideoUrl" type="video/mp4">         
    </video>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have read, it won't be available in ngOninit, but not able to understand why it is not acceble in ngAfterViewInit().. your help is appreciated

Comment: Is the `videoPlayer` inside of a `*ngIf`?

Comment: Yes, my whole component template is inside *ngIf like below

`<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between start" class="ats-analyzer ats-p-t-10" *ngIf=" currentParticipant">

    <div fxFlex="45%" class="ats-analyzer--video ats-p-r-10">
        <video controls #videoPlayer>
            <source [src]="atsAnalyzerVideoUrl" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: Can you please provide the code where `currentParticipant` will be set

Comment: It is set initially in ngOnit to first element by default out of some service response

` **ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadInsights(); // Here there is an api call, and out of that service call subscription, I am setting currentparticipant
    });**
`

Please excuse for formatting, not able to format code well here in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ViewChild` is still undefined in `ngAfterViewInit` because it isn't created yet at that time. This belongs to the wrapping `*ngIf` around it since it is only created as soon as the `currentParticipant` has been set to a truthy value.

Based on your comment I assume that the `currentParticipant` is set after a HTTP request or another async operation.

Let assume your code to get the  `currentParticipant` looks like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.someService.getCurrentParticipant().subscribe((currParticipant) => {
    this.currentParticipant = currParticipant;
  });
}
```

In this case, your `ViewChild` becomes only available after an execution of the subscription where a **truthy value** is written to `currentParticipant`.

To make your example working where you want to write the duration of the video to a service you have 2 options:

1. Use `ViewChildren` because then you can listen to changes ([docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#description))
2. You can use setter/getter on your `ViewChild` and update your service in the setter

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined).