# Child component values are null when referenced from parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component and a child component. The child has a form which needs to be saved if the user has changed it and tries to navigate away by clicking a link on the parent.

**Parent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.html',
  providers: [MessageService]    
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild('child') child: ChildComponent;
  message: any;
```

The ChildComponent has a form with lots of data entered. It also has an object called *user* which must have permission to save the form.

**child**

```
 save() {
   if (this.user.role <= 2) postFormDataToDb();
```

In the parent, when a link is clicked to navigate away, it calls

```
this.child.save();
```

The error I get is that *this.child* is null.  I could be wrong, but it seems like ChildComponent is a new instance with everything empty, rather than the existing one. Yet it seems like the form is in the DOM since I can inspect one of the fields and it shows up.

I've tried several different approaches but all produce a null error.
I've tried using a shared MessageService and subscribing to it.

```
this.subManager = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
  this.message = message;
  console.log("message=",message);
});
this.sendMessage('save');
```

but the message never gets to the button (nothing shows up in the div).

```
<div *ngIf="message" (click)="saveUsers()">{{message.text}}</div>
```

I've tried loading just the #saveBtn from the child form

```
@ViewChild('saveBtn') saveBtn: ElementRef;
```

and clicking it with

```
this.saveBtn.nativeElement.click();
```

from the parent component.  Error says this.saveBtn is null.

The provided link seems like it might be a duplicate question, but the solutions involve *ngIf which I don't use, except to display the message.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 @ViewChild annotation returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined)

Comment: the child component is rendering in dom when you call the save method?

Comment: Yes.  The parent component is a navigation menu on the left and the child component is on the right, completely rendered and filled with data.

Comment: The link seems to deal with *ngIf causing the problem.  I'm not using those.  My guess is that @ViewChild is referencing an empty ChildComponent when ParentComponent is created.  Later when ChildComponent gets instantiated, ParentComponent still points to the empty one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work using conventional javascript way by adding `id="saveBtn"` to button and

```
document.getElementById('saveBtn').click();
```

in the parent.ts file.