# ViewRef is undefined when component gets initialized on "browser back" action

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component which contains `<ng-template #placeholder></ng-template>` in its template to insert components dynamically. In OnInit a "loadComponents" method is called which uses the viewRef, but is unable on the second time it loads:

```
@ViewChild("placeholder", { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false })
private viewRef: ViewContainerRef;

private loadComponents() {
    if (this.viewRef) {
      this.viewRef.clear();
      this.criteria.forEach((criterion) => {
        if (Object.keys(this.componentMap).includes(criterion.type)) {
          const componentFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(
            this.componentMap[criterion.type]
          );
          const componentRef = this.viewRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

This component is a form for a search component which it includes.

After starting the search, the search component shows the data below and has links to the detail views. But when I open the detail view and go back to the search page -- which holds the search criteria in a store -- the viewRef is undefined.
When I check it "later" with the Angular Tools then viewRef is defined. So I guess it is injected after OnInit.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Yep, @ViewChild are available in AfterViewInit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle when the decorator includes `static: true`, then it becomes available in ngOnInit.

Comment: @Apollo do you have some `routeReuseStrategy` in your routing logic ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle hmm then I run into issues with changed after init. Perhaps I need to use Change Detection on push here. And I don't use `routeReuseStrategy`.

Comment: @temp_user I changed it to `static: true` but it is still undefined in my loadComponents method. Any ideas why? Now even the initial load does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution. I created a new sub component which wraps the placeholder. I did not need ChangeDetection OnPush in the view ref. But the loadComponents not gets triggered in ngOnChanges.