# Using ElementRef with async pipe

Tags: angular, async-pipe, elementref

In my html i have async pipe and ElementReference.
In ts iam setting data comes with async pipe to nativeElement.innerHTML but iam getting this on console.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')

Html

```
<div *ngIf="(article$ | async) as article">

    <div #articleBody>
    </div>

</div>
```

Ts

```
@ViewChild("articleBody") articleBody: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.article$ = this.articleService.article$.pipe(
      tap(x => {
        this.articleBody.nativeElement.innerHTML = x.body
      })
    )
  }
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 @ViewChild annotation returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined)

Comment: `ViewChild` doesn't work well when the element is inside a conditional `ngIf` block. The linked post gives alternate suggestions.

Comment: a couple of answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/viewchild-in-ngif

Comment: Have you tried adding a set timeout? Around the reference to give time for the dom to draw?

Comment: @JudsonTerrell yes settimeout works , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle this with run change detector manually. Angular will init `ViewChild` on `ngAfterInit` but you init the data in it, too. So try this

```
…

constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.article$ = this.articleService.article$.pipe(
      tap(x => {
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
        this.articleBody.nativeElement.innerHTML = x.body
      })
    )
  }
```

This force Angular to check all changes. Then your ViewChild is available.

Comment: This does not solve problem but setTimeout works.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution than the timeout would be relying on  `ViewChildren` and subscribing to its `changes`.

Something like :

```
@ViewChildren('articleBody', {read: ElementRef}) el: QueryList<ElementRef>;

/**
 * Listen within this component
 */
private listenForPlotChanges() {
    this.el.changes.subscribe(
        (next: QueryList<ElementRef>) => {
            // check the length if the elements has been rendered. 
         }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned just use a setTimeout around your function. This is used very commonly to avoid these types of issues.

```
cont t = setTimeout(()=>{
//do something
clearTimeout(t) // avoid memory leak
},1)
```