# I want to get element via ViewChild in TS file, Angular version is 15

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild, angular15

When I try to log a `ViewChild` element in `ngAfterViewInit()` or `ngOnInit()` it logs `undefined` in the console.

HTML file:

```html
<input type="number" #phoneNumber>
```

TS file:

```js
@ViewChild('phoneNumber',{static:false}) phoneNumber: ElementRef;

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.phoneNumber);
}

ngAfterViewInit():void{
  console.log(this.phoneNumber);
}
```

I did every way to get element via `ViewChild` it won't work. How do I get a reference to my input using the `ViewChild` decorator?

Comment: Is the input field (or any of its ancestors) rendered conditionally? `ViewChild` won't return a reference to the element until it is rendered

Comment: Yes, it is inside the condition, then how can I get the element in the TS file?

Comment: Please, edit your question in order to show us the details including the condition that causes the issue following @AliNauman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewChild` will not return a reference for an element that is rendered conditionally until the condition becomes truthy.

In this case, you can use a setter for the ViewChild decorated property, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47519683/9917250) answer:

```js
 @ViewChild('phoneNumber') set phoneNumber(
    elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined
  ) {
    console.log(elementRef);
  }
```